# Post a link to Facebook including an UIImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook

I want to post a link including an image to Facebook timeline:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
    self.postParams =
    [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
     @"Here we go", @"message",
     @"https://developers.facebook.com/ios", @"link",
     UIImagePNGRepresentation(img), @"picture",
     @"Facebook SDK for iOS", @"name",
     @"Build great social apps and get more installs.", @"caption",
     @"The Facebook SDK for iOS makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated iOS apps.", @"description",
     nil];

    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" parameters:self.postParams HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                              [self showAlert:@"Link is posted" result:result error:error];
    }];
```

The UIImage does not posted. Can you help me?

But simply if I use :

```
@"https://developers.facebook.com/attachment/iossdk_logo.png", @"picture"
```

it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts), it says the "picture" parameter should be of type string ie: a url. You can not post an image and a message from the mobile SDKs at the same time without some clever hackory: see me/photos in the documentation but your options are severely limited.

Comment: You are completely right. what about if I make a URL from my UIImage and then use that string in my params?

Comment: yes, if you follow the instructions in the doc it will usually work